# xbindkeys: Conflicting program

Tags: 13.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, mouse, keys

So my issue is I just reinstalled Ubuntu 13.04 and as always I install `xbindkeys` and set up my search button to be middle click and the scroll wheel side clicks to copy/paste. However it was working but after a reboot it didn't start. Tried to manually start but nothing, and `xbindkeys -n` shows:

```
*** Warning *** Please verify that there is not another program running
which captures one of the keys captured by xbindkeys. It seems that there
is a conflict, and xbindkeys can't grab all the keys defined in its
configuration file.
```

How can I find out what is conflicting with `xbindkeys`? I disabled the Search key shortcut in the **Settings > Keyboard** which worked last time but this time its not helping.

Comment: Having the same issue on Ubuntu 14.10

Comment: What's the output of `xmodmap -pk` and `localectl`?

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I see is to kill processes one by one and try to run `xbindkeys -n` each time. Then you will be able to deduce which process occupies your key combinations. To identify which PIDs you should kill look at `ps aufx|grep $(whoami)`. Start with obvious ones, then continue with leaves except of course non-X applications (bash, mc, etc.) and your terminal application. Unless you kill your terminal app you should be able to proceed.

Answer (score -1):

Cite from [Community Help Wiki - Keyboard Shortcuts](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KeyboardShortcuts)

> #### Laptop Function Shortcuts
>
> Many laptops have function <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys which you can hold down
>   to access more functions on the laptop's keyboard. A list of these
>   functions should be available from the manufacturer of the laptop.
>
> #### Text Entry Shortcuts
>
> If you want to have quick access to lines of text by using a hotkey,
>   for example to enter your email address in forms, then you can use
>   `xbindkeys`. **Xbindkeys** has a GUI utility to allow easy settings of
>   hotkeys, but be aware that it's a little more complicated than the
>   default Ubuntu Shortcutkeys interface.
>
> 1. Install `xbindkeys`:
>
>    ```
>    sudo apt-get install xbindkeys
>    ```
> 2. Create the default config file for `xbindkeys`:
>
>    ```
>    xbindkeys --defaults > /home/your-user-name/.xbindkeysrc
>    ```
> 3. When thats done, install `xbindkeys-config`, the GUI for `xbindkeys`:
>
>    ```
>    sudo apt-get install xbindkeys-config
>    ```
> 4. Now the utility that actually does the "typing":
>
>    ```
>    sudo apt-get install xvkbd
>    ```
> 5. Once each is installed, start both applications by bringing up **Run
>      Application** <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>:
>
>    ```
>    xbindkeys
>    ```
> 6. and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>:
>
>    ```
>    xbindkeys-config
>    ```
>
> To keep the `xbindkeys` hotkeys active when you next start the
>   computer you will have to add a new session, **System > Preferences >
>   Sessions**. Put in the command `xbindkeys` into the command field.
>
> You should be able to see the **Xbindkeys Config** window. Start a new
>   hotkey. Hit **New** on the bottom row of buttons. Then use the edit
>   area at the top right. Give the hotkey a name. Hit the **GetKey**
>   button to set the keypress for a hotkey. Some hotkeys may conflict
>   with other hotkeys on the system (a window will open or a **compiz**
>   plugin will activate). If this happens then choose another combination
>   like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> for example.
>
> Now put the command to activate with that hotkey in the **Action**
>   field. This can be anything, but to allow for the entry of a line of
>   text into part of the GUI enter
>
> ```
> xvkbd -xsendevent -text "myemail@server.com"
> ```
>
> The example shows an email address but it can be any line of text. Now
>   hit **Apply** and test the hotkey in a Firefox field, text editor, or
>   anywhere that text can be entered. Please note that using **Run
>   Action** will not be able to test the command in `xbindkeys-config`,
>   you will have to test it somewhere else.
>
> #### Replacing keys with other keys
>
> If you want to use `xbindkeys` to override certain keys on your
>   keyboard, you can catch them with `xbindkeys`, and then emit new
>   keypresses using `xmacro`. To install `xmacro`, use:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install xmacro
> ```
>
> After this, you can find out the commands for specific keypresses by
>   starting `xmacrorec`:
>
> ```
> xmacrorec :0.0
> ```
>
> First give it the key which will allow you to quit the app, then press
>   the keys you want to know the codes for. After this, you can use those
>   codes in the commands you tell `xbindkeys` to run, for example:
>
> ```
> xmacroplay-keys :0.0 KeyStr Next
> ```
>
> *will simulate a key press of the <kbd>PageDown</kbd> key. Thus, in my `.xbindkeysrc` the following contents*
>
> ```
> "xmacroplay-keys :0.0 KeyStr Prior"
>   XF86Back
>
> "xmacroplay-keys :0.0 KeyStr Next"
>   XF86Forward
> ```
>
> *will turn the <kbd>Backward</kbd>/<kbd>Forward</kbd> buttons on my Thinkpad T41 into <kbd>PageDown</kbd> and <kbd>PageUp</kbd> keys, and
>   will no longer disturb my browsing as I accidentally press those
>   <kbd>Backward</kbd>/<kbd>Forward</kbd> while browsing.*